# How to bind a dynamic <img> id to a JavaScript event?

Tags: vuejs2

I am learning how to use a Javascript image annotation library called [Annotorious](https://github.com/recogito/annotorious). I want to integrate it into a Vue app and it works fine if I do this:

`<img :src="photo.url" id="dog" :alt="photo.title" />`

However, I am getting a console error if I do it like so:

`<img :src="photo.url" :id="photo.id" :alt="photo.title" />`

> My full code for the SFC named `PhotoDetail.vue`: [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-greider-ri1w7?file=/src/components/PhotoDetail.vue:0-953)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Test Photo</h1>
    <img :src="photo.url" :id="photo.id" :alt="photo.title" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Annotorious } from '@recogito/annotorious'
export default {
  name: 'photoDetail',
  data() {
    return {
      photo: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getPhoto() {
      this.photo.url = await 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/400/'
      this.photo.id = 'dog'
      this.photo.title = 'nice dog'
    },
    annotatePhoto() {
      try {
        const anno = new Annotorious({
          image: this.photo.id // image element or ID
        })
        // Attach listeners to handle annotation events
        anno.on('createAnnotation', function(annotation) {
          console.log('Created!', annotation)
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('anno error', error)
      }
    }
  },
  async created() {
    await this.getPhoto()
  },
  mounted() {
    this.annotatePhoto()
  }
}
</script>
```

Console error:

```
anno error TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined
    at new e (annotorious.min.js:1)
    at VueComponent.annotatePhoto (cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/PhotoDetail.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:51)
    at VueComponent.mounted (cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/PhotoDetail.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:84)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js:1853)
    at callHook (vue.runtime.esm.js:4213)
    at Object.insert (vue.runtime.esm.js:3136)
    at invokeInsertHook (vue.runtime.esm.js:6336)
    at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (vue.runtime.esm.js:6555)
    at VueComponent.Vue._update (vue.runtime.esm.js:3942)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:4060)
```

Any advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to make sure the `img` component is rendered before calling `annotatePhoto` function. That is, after `getPhoto` function:

```
async mounted() {
  await this.getPhoto()
  this.annotatePhoto()
}
```

You also need to change the way you update the `photo` variable like this, or the DOM won't update:

```
this.photo = {
  url: await 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/400/',
  id: 'dog',
  title: 'nice dog',
}
```

Working example: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-https-fejxz?file=/src/components/PhotoDetail.vue)

Comment: I'll take a look at this later today, but wanted to first tell you thank you for taking the time to help me! I'll mark it as answered once I give it a try.